# PayPal's CallerServices Works on localhost but not server

Tags: paypal, paypal-soap

My PayPal Direct script works perfect on my machine. Both nUnit tests and via a website on localhost. However this first line of code fails on my server and another server. (both full trust)

```
CallerServices caller = new CallerServices();
```

**Message**: The type initializer for 'com.paypal.sdk.core.soap.SOAPAPICaller' threw an exception.
**Source**: paypal_base

Stack Trace:

at com.paypal.sdk.core.soap.SOAPAPICaller..ctor()
   at com.paypal.sdk.services.CallerServices..ctor()
   at TS.Common.BusinessLogic.PaymentGateways.PayPalProController.CChargeCard(String paymentAmount, Order CurrentOrder, String creditCardType, String creditCardNumber, String CVV2, String expMonth, String expYear, PaymentActionCodeType paymentAction, Transaction& transaction)
   at TS.Common.BusinessLogic.PaymentGateways.PayPalProController.ChargeCard(Order CurrentOrder, Decimal Amount, String CreditCardNum, String ExpMonth, String ExpYear, String SecurityNumber, Transaction& transaction)
   at OrderController.SubmitCreditCardPayment(Order order, Decimal ChargeAmount, String CreditCardNum, String ExpMonth, String ExpYear, String Var, String CardType, Transaction& transaction)
   at OrderController.SubmitOrder(Order order, Transaction& transaction, Nullable`1 GiftCertId, String CreditCardNum, String ExpMonth, String ExpYear, String Var, String CardType, String Culture)
   at Checkout.btnOrder_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Inetpub\tickets\Checkout.aspx.cs:line 488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add log4net.dll , if not put it in your bin folder and add reference. It works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Add the reference to the log4net.dll with the specific version only. It will work